React Native 0.73 mysterious build error error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(7042) deny(1) file-write-create
I would like to know why my build fails when running react-native run-ios or building in xCode.
Sandbox: rsync.samba(7041) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/-ajen010/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/itstime-fusdcdrjasehwueoyulohqzxdotg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework/_CodeSignature (in target 'itstime' from project 'itstime')
error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(7042) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/ajen010/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/itstime-fusdcdrjasehwueoyulohqzxdotg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/itstime.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework/_CodeSignature (in target 'itstime' from project 'itstime')
error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(7041) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/ajen010/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/itstime-fusdcdrjasehwueoyulohqzxdotg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework/Info.plist (in target 'itstime' from project 'itstime')
error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(7043) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/ajen010/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/itstime-fusdcdrjasehwueoyulohqzxdotg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/itstime.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework/.double-conversion.4nf1M8

I know I can turn off User Scripting Sandbox in xCode as a workaround but I would like a real fix rather than a workaround.
System:
  OS: macOS 14.4.1
  CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M2 Pro
  Memory: 113.09 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: 3.2.57
    path: /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.20.1
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.1/bin/node
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm:
    version: 10.5.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.1/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.04.01.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.15.2
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.2
      - iOS 17.2
      - macOS 14.2
      - tvOS 17.2
      - visionOS 1.0
      - watchOS 10.2
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2023.2 AI-232.10300.40.2321.11567975
  Xcode:
    version: 15.2/15C500b
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 20.0.2.1
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 3.1.4
    path: /Users/andrewjennings/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.4/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.73.6
    wanted: 0.73.6
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false

I'm trying to build my react-native application.
I tried:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
chmod -R u+rwX ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

I tried deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
I gave terminal and xCode full disk access
I know I can turn off User Scripting Sandbox in xCode as a workaround, but I would like a real fix rather than a workaround.
